# R functions that operate on data frame columns

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have the following function:

```
calculateAngle <- function(x, y)
{
    v <- c(x, y)
    a <- c(1, 0)

    theta <- acos( sum(a*v) / ( sqrt(sum(a * a)) * sqrt(sum(v * v)) ) )

    if(v[[2]] < 0)
    {
        return(-1 * theta)
    }
    else
    {
        return(theta)
    }
}
```

Which takes an x and y value and calculates the angle between that vector and a vector of 1, 0.  Now, this function works fine in these examples:

```
> calculateAngle(0, 1)
[1] 1.570796
> calculateAngle(0, -1)
[1] -1.570796
> calculateAngle(0, -10)
[1] -1.570796
> calculateAngle(rnorm(1), rnorm(1))
[1] -0.2600444
```

But when I try to pass it the columns of a dataframe, it returns a single value when what I want is the angle for each row.

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))

df$angle <- calculateAngle(df$x, df$y)
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for `theta` is overly complicated, for example you have term `sum(sqrt(a*a))` which is always 1, and `sum(a*v)` is always `x`. Also `sum(v*v) = x^2+y^2`, and using that form we get to the version which works also for vector arguments:

```
calculateAngle <- function(x, y)
{
   a <- c(1, 0)
   theta <- acos( x / sqrt(x^2+y^2))
   sign(y)*theta
}
```

Comment: So maybe we can remove `v` entirely...?

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Spent so much time looking for the code answer when algebra would have done.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

(Warning: this is the lazy answer because I don't feel like spending more than 5 seconds on this!)

```
calculateAnglev <- Vectorize(calculateAngle,c('x','y'))
> calculateAnglev(runif(2),runif(2))
[1] 0.2738694 0.8039875
```

i.e. this should not be mistaken for a substitute for true vectorization, performance-wise.

Comment: FWIW, the issue is the `sum` function which takes a vector and returns a scalar.

Comment: I'm wondering if this will hit an issue in the OP's `if` statement at the end of the function? (ie if x is longer than y)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I'm not sure. This is just a wrapper for `mapply` and the OP's function. So if the original function works, this will work. But Hemmo's answer is better.

Comment: Joran, you're answer if helpful too.  I'll know to look at Vectorize for future problems.  Thanks!